# Elixir type spec for a function with default parameters

Tags: elixir

How do I write a type spec for the function that accepts, let's say, one parameter which has a default value? Something like the following:

```elixir
def foo(bar \\ 10) do
  bar
end
```

Would it be this:

```elixir
@spec foo(integer) :: integer
```

Or what would it be?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes.

I would add that if your question is if there is a difference between the typespec of a function which has an argument with a default value and an argument that doesn't, then no there is no difference.

Comment: This answer is accepted but does not seem strictly speaking accurate, or at least not complete. As the other answer explains more explicitly, the sample type spec would only cover _one_ of the generated functions. This answer makes it sound like that's all that would ever be necessary, but if you want to create a spec for the other function (0 arity in this example), you need a separate typespec for that.

Answer (score 4):

It works as expected because you actually define two functions.

```elixir
@spec foo(integer) :: integer
def foo(bar \\ 10) do
  bar
end
```

Is equivalent to:

```elixir
def foo() do
  foo(10)
end

@spec foo(integer) :: integer
def foo(bar) do
  bar
end
```

So you basically end up with two functions but only one of them has `@spec`.

Comment: So can the spec be described in a way that supports both cases?

Comment: No, to cover both functions with specs you need to explicitly define them and write their specs.