# Ecto.Repo.delete/2: When looking at a type specification, how do you know if there is a default value?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Here's the type specification:

```
iex(1)> h Ecto.Repo.delete
No documentation for function Ecto.Repo.delete was found, but there is a callback with the same name.
You can view callback documentations with the b/1 helper.

iex(2)> b Ecto.Repo.delete
@callback delete(
            struct_or_changeset :: 
              Ecto.Schema.t() | Ecto.Changeset.t(),
            opts :: Keyword.t()
          ) ::
            {:ok, Ecto.Schema.t()}
            | {:error, Ecto.Changeset.t()}

Deletes a struct using its primary key.

If the struct has no primary key,
Ecto.NoPrimaryKeyFieldError will be raised. If the struct
has been removed from db prior to call,
Ecto.StaleEntryError will be raised.

It returns {:ok, struct} if the struct has been
successfully deleted or {:error, changeset} if there was a
validation or a known constraint error.

## Options

  • :prefix - The prefix to run the query on (such as
    the schema path in Postgres or the database in MySQL).
    This overrides the prefix set in the query and any
    @schema_prefix set in the schema.
  • :stale_error_field - The field where stale errors
    will be added in the returning changeset. This option
    can be used to avoid raising Ecto.StaleEntryError.
  • :stale_error_message - The message to add to the
    configured :stale_error_field when stale errors happen,
    defaults to "is stale".

See the "Shared options" section at the module
documentation.

## Example

    post = MyRepo.get!(Post, 42)
    case MyRepo.delete post do
      {:ok, struct}       -> # Deleted with success
      {:error, changeset} -> # Something went wrong
    end
```

In the example at the end there, delete() is being called with one argument.  And, I can successfully call `delete()` with one argument:

```
  def delete_item(%Auction.Item{}=item) do
    @repo.delete(item)  #<=== HERE
  end
```

So, that tells me that the second argument must have a default value.  Is there a way to know that somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Browsing through the docs and a [similar question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37417909/2112512), it seems that default arguments are not supported in typespecs. [This Github issue](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/issues/2683) from 2014 explains some of the tradeoffs to such a feature.

How would one know the second argument is optional? Besides source-diving the Elixir code, hopefully it is documented. In the case of this version of `Ecto.Repo.delete`, the argument is named `opts` in the typespec, and described under a heading 'Options', which to me strongly suggests that they are optional.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the callback is implemented.

You cannot have default arguments in callback specification, but you can define a function with default arguments that implements a callback.

```
defmodule Converter do
  @doc """
  Callback doc.
  """
  @callback convert(number(), any(), any()) :: number()
end

defmodule MyConverter do
  @behaviour Converter

  def convert(number, from_unit \\ :km, to_unit \\ :miles) do
    # ...
  end
end
```

However this is not enough for `IEx.Helpers.h` macro to actually show what the default arguments are, because it works with explicitly defined docs.

In the example above, the only the `@doc` for callback specification is definied, so it will be shown.

```
iex> h MyConverter.convert
@callback convert(number(), any(), any()) :: number()

Callback doc.
```

You'd actually need to define `@doc` for the function that implements the callback to achieve what you want.

```
defmodule MyConverter do
  @behaviour Converter

  @doc """
  Implementation docs.
  """
  def convert(number, from_unit \\ :km, to_unit \\ :miles) do
    # ...
  end
end

iex> h MyConverter.convert

            def convert(number, from_unit \\ :km, to_unit \\ :miles)

Implementation docs.
```

Now to relate to the case outlined in your question: when using `Ecto.Repo`, it defines a function in `MyApp.Repo` module that implements `delete` callback but without module docs. That's why you cannot see the default arguments for this function via IEx helpers.